# Difference between Loading a class using ClassLoader and Class.forName

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Below are 2 code snippets

**The first one uses ClassLoader class to load a specified class**

`ClassLoader cls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class someClass = cls.loadClass("TargetClass");`

**The second one uses Class.forName() to load a specified class**

`Class cls = Class.forName("TargetClass");`

What is the difference between the above said approaches. Which one serves for which purpose?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick answer (without code samples)

With the explicit `ClassLoader cls = <a ClassLoader>;` approach you have the flexibility of loading the class from a ClassLoader that is *not* your default ClassLoader.  In your case you're using the default System ClassLoader, so it gives the similar overall result (with an instantiation of the final object difference) as the `Class.forName(String name)` call, but you *could* reference another ClassLoader instead.

That said, you can also use `Class.forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)` as long as you know what that ClassLoader is.

For example, your EAR based application has its own ClassLoader with a version of an XML Parsing library wrapped inside of it.  Your code normally uses those classes, but in one instance you need to grab a deserialisation class from an earlier version of the library (that the Application Server happens to be holding in *its* overall ClassLoader).  So you could reference that Application Server ClassLoader instead.

Unfortunately until we get project Jigsaw (JDK 8) this is used more often than we'd like :-)

Comment: Don't forget: objects instantiated from classes loaded by different class loaders are not `Equal()`, even if their data is the same.  Even if they're created from the same class (loaded by two different class loaders).  This can be the source of excruciatingly hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Actually, @TMN is wrong. Let `cl1` and `cl2` be two different class loaders, and let `A` be a class that override `.equals(...)` with `return true;` (that is, it will always return true). Then `cl1.loadClass("A").newInstance().equals(cl2.loadClass("B").newInstance())` returns true.

Comment: What does "forName" mean? It's a strange method name. Why isn't it load?

Comment: Yeah, the naming there is a little strange to say the least :-)

Answer (score 53):

The other answers are very complete in that they explore other overloads of `Class.forName(...)`, and talk about the possibility to use different ClassLoaders.

However they fail to answer your direct question: "What is the difference between the above said approaches?", which deals with one specific overload of `Class.forName(...)`. And they miss one very important difference. **Class initialization**.

Consider the following class:

```
public class A {
  static { System.out.println("time = " + System.currentTimeMillis()); }
}
```

Now consider the following two methods:

```
public class Main1 {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    final Class<?> c = Class.forName("A");
  }
}

public class Main2 {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("A");
  }
}
```

The first class, `Main1`, when run, will produce an output such as

```
time = 1313614183558
```

The other, however, will produce no output at all. That means that the class `A`, although loaded, has not been initialized (ie, it's `<clinit>` has not been called). Actually, you can even query the class's members through reflection before the initialization!

Why would you care?

There are classes that performs some kind of important initialization or registration upon initialization.

For example, JDBC specifies interfaces that are implemented by different providers. To use MySQL, you usually do `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`. That is, you load **and initialize** the class. I've never seen that code, but obviously the static constructor of that class must register the class (or something else) somewhere with JDBC.

If you did `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`, you would not be able to use JDBC, since the class, altough loaded, has not been initialized (and then JDBC wouldn't know which implementation to use, just as if you had not loaded the class).

So, this is the difference between the two methods you asked.

Comment: @Bruno, Nitpicking here on your sentences, but we usually *don't* do `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while/8053125#8053125 . Anyhow, what I wanted to ask is Is there any way to initialize a class using ClassLoader?

Comment: @Pacarier, nowadays, we usually don't do that when dealing with modern code. That's is only (still) needed when you deal with legacy code. And yes, you can initialize a class using `Class.forName(String, true, ClassLoader)`. See the api docs for Class.forName for more information.

Answer (score 13):

In your concrete case:

```
ClassLoader cls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class someClass = cls.loadClass("TargetClass");
```

Above code will load `TargetClass` **ALWAYS** with [system classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()).

```
Class cls = Class.forName("TargetClass");
```

The second code snippet will load (and initialise) `TargetClass` with **the classloader that was used to load the class that is executing that line of code**. If that class was loaded with system classloader, the two approaches are identical (except for class initialisation, as explained in an excellent answer by Bruno).

**Which one to use?** For loading and inspecting classes with reflection, I  recommend to use specific class loader (`ClassLoader.loadClass()`) - it puts you in control and helps to avoid potentially obscure issues between different environments.

If you need to load AND initialise, use `Class.forName(String, true, ClassLoader)`.

**How to find the right class loader?** It depends on your environment:

- if you are running a **command-line application**, you could just use [system classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) or the class loader that loaded your application classes (`Class.getClassLoader()`).
- if you are running inside a **managed environment** (JavaEE, servlet container, etc) then the best would be to check [current thread context class loader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) first and then fall back to options given in previous point.
- or just use your own **custom class loader** (if you are into that sort of thing)

In general, **the most fool-proof** and tested would be to use `ClassUtils.forName()` from Spring (see [JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html)).

**More in-depth explanation:**

---

> The most common form of `Class.forName()`, the one that takes a single `String` parameter, always uses the caller's classloader. This is the classloader that loads the code executing the `forName()` method. By comparison, `ClassLoader.loadClass()` is an instance method and requires you to select a particular classloader, which may or may not be the loader that loads that calling code. If picking a specific loader to load the class is important to your design, you should use `ClassLoader.loadClass()` or the three-parameter version of `forName()` added in *Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE)*: `Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader)`.

Source: [What is the difference between `Class.forName()` and `ClassLoader.loadClass()`?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-03/01-qa-0314-forname.html)

---

Also, [SPR-2611](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2611) highlights one interesting obscure corner case when using `Class.forName(String, boolean, ClassLoader)`.

As seen in that Spring issue, using ClassLoader.loadClass() is **the recommended approach** (when you need to load classes from specific class loader).

Comment: This is an excellent and comprehensive answer and should have been the accepted one.

Comment: This is more complete than the accepted answer.  System vs thread vs calling-class loader is a tricky concept.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassLoader.loadClass()` uses the specified classloader (the system classloader in your case), whereas `Class.forName()` uses classloader of the current class.

`Class.forName()` can be used when you don't care about particular classloader and want the same classloading behaviour as for statically referenced classes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):

> Invoking this method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>   Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
> ```
>
> where currentLoader denotes the defining class loader of the current
>   class.

So the main difference is in which classloader will be used (it may or may not be the same as the system classloader). 
The overloaded method would also allow you to specify the classloader to use explicitly.

Comment: Class.forName() can be more error prone in reality (as opposed to ClassLoader.loadClass()), see https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-2611

Answer (score 1):

ClassLoader.loadClass() always loads the system classloader, whereas Class.forName()  loades any class. Lets see this example,

```
package com;
public class TimeA {
      public static void main (String args[]) {
            try {
                final Class c = Class.forName("com.A");
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.A");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
      }
}

class A {
      static {
          System.out.println("time = " + System.currentTimeMillis()); 
      }
}
```

When yoy run this program, you would get an Exception at `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("com.A");`

The Output may be:

```
time = 1388864219803
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.A
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd approach loads a class using a `ClassLoader`

```
 public static Class<?> forName(String className) 
                throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return forName0(className, true, ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader());
```

This is what the JavaDoc says:

```
forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)
```

> The specified class loader is used to
>   load the class or interface. If the
>   parameter loader is null, the class is
>   loaded through the bootstrap class
>   loader.

So, the 2nd option uses the System ClassLoader (which is, in essence, what it does in the first option).

Answer (score 0):

there's also a difference when loading array-types. I think `classloader.loadClass(clazz)` cannot handle array-types, but `Class.forName(clazz,true,classloader)` can.

Answer (score 0):

But the static initilizer block is only executed when we use class.forname("...");

I have just tested.