# Why Java class loader executes "static" content, like Class.forName

Tags: java, class, static, loader

I googled the difference between ClassLoader and Class.forName, most answer say that Class.forName will operate the "static" section of a class, while ClassLoader doesn't. So I tested this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ClassLoader l = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Class c2 = l.loadClass("C");
        Constructor ctor2 = c2.getConstructor();
        C obj2 = (C) ctor2.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
static
default ctor
```

Well, not my expected, why and when does ClassLoader execute "static" section, anyway? If it also executes "static", then what's the core difference between these 2?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l.loadClass("C");` [will not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099453/6690200) leading to execute static initializers, while creating an instance does.

You can remove below code and try it again:

```
Constructor ctor2 = c2.getConstructor();
C obj2 = (C) ctor2.ne
```