# How to deserialize objects using a custom class loader?

Tags: java

In a project, I need to extend the standard class loader with a custom class loader. The main motivation for this is that the classpath is extended during run time. (For a solution to this problem see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584718/231397 ).

Serializing objects via

```
ObjectOutputStream out;
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  out.writeObject(object);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (IOException e) { }
finally {
  out.close();
}
```

works fine, while deserializing objects via

```
Object object = null;
ObjectInputStream in;
try {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  object = in.readObject();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
finally {
  in.close();
}
```

fails with a `ClassNotFoundException` exception. The reason is that the standard class loader is invoked, which does not know about the custom class loader.

**Q: What is the correct way to deserialize objects using a custom class loader?**

Answer (score 4):

(Note: Having searched for solutions on the net, I give an answer to my own question. Some solutions one finds on the net is “almost correct”: it does not work for inner classes).

The solution is to extend `ObjectInputStream` and override the method `resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass)`
This can be done with an anonymous class. Then use `Class.forName` inside `resolveClass` with the custom classloader. That is

```
Object object = null;
try {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis) {
    @Override
    public Class resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      try {
        return Class.forName(desc.getName(), true, customClassLoader);
      } catch (Exception e) { }

      // Fall back (e.g. for primClasses)
      return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }
  };

  object = in.readObject();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
finally {
  in.close();
}
```

*Remark*: You may find solutions suggesting to use

```
customClassLoader.loadClass(desc.getName());
```

instead of

```
Class.forName(desc.getName(), true, customClassLoader)
```

While this may work in many cases, it may have issues. For example I found that `customClassLoader.loadClass(desc.getName())` does not work for inner classes (possibly due to difference in naming for an inner class B of a class A in package p resolving to p.A.B or to p.A$B). Also note that `loadClass` does not initialize the class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099453/231397